# Requirejs function in define not executed

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My directory structure looks something like this:

```
\js
   ...
   \models\...
   ...
   \test
        \test_runner.js
        \error_test.js
        ...
   main_tests.js
```

Where I have the following code in `main_tests.js`:

```
requirejs(['test/test_runner'],function(){
  console.log('Testing begins');
});
```

The `test_runner.js` looks like this:

```
define('test_runner',['test/error_test'],function(){
   console.log("in test_runner");
});
```

and the `error_test.js` is like this:

```
define('error_test',['modules/error'],function() {
   console.log('in erro_test');
});
```

As you might have figured out I want to run from the `test_runner.js` some tests. I need `main_tests.js` in order to define the dependencies for the application to be tested. I can set up the application to work(it's ember based). When I run the code for the tests it loads the `test_runner.js`, but it does not execute it and it also doesn't loads its dependencies(`error_test.js`).

Any thoughts why it does not do the thing?

Comment: Is it a typo in your sample only `['modules/error']function` ?

Comment: yes, I'll correct it - thanks, but it does not affect my problem, since as I said, that part of the app does not even load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In requireJS you've redefined `'test/test_runner'` module as `'test_runner'`

You should define `test_runner.js` without renaming the module:

```
define(['test/error_test'], function(){
   console.log("in test_runner");
});
```

As a rule of thumb, models should be referred to by their full path & name. They shouldn't be renamed by passing in the 1st param.

See the [official docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename)